# Strange RGB color in LaTeX: xcolor + definecolor

Tags: color

I'm trying to use the RGB color (0, 127, 255) in Latex, but I got another color (it seems cyan). I tried it in Texmaker and in Overleaf, the result is the same. How can I overcome this problem?

**[Desired color](https://www.google.com/search?q=rgb%200%20127%20255&sxsrf=ALiCzsZUdfsw2kTBxVcHd68jMdE1qMj2ow%3A1656520568638&source=hp&ei=eH-8Ys2II_aG9u8PoImZkAo&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYryNiIRGgF6e3K5I9PFuRBrHHEtc62Ew&ved=0ahUKEwjNpLaAjNP4AhV2g_0HHaBEBqIQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=rgb%200%20127%20255&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCAghEB4QFhAdMggIIRAeEBYQHTIICCEQHhAWEB0yCAghEB4QFhAdMggIIRAeEBYQHTIICCEQHhAWEB0yCgghEB4QDxAWEB0yCgghEB4QDxAWEB0yCgghEB4QDxAWEB0yCAghEB4QFhAdOgQIIxAnOgQIABBDOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6CAguELEDEIMBOgoIABCxAxCDARBDOgQILhBDOgcIABCxAxBDOgUIABCABDoKCAAQgAQQhwIQFDoGCAAQHhAWOggIABAeEA8QFlAAWKQeYPAfaABwAHgBgAHFAYgB-gySAQQyLjExmAEAoAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)**:

[image]

**Color obtained**:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Immagini/} }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\definecolor{myBlue}{rgb}{0, 127, 255}


\title{
Template
}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
\textcolor{myBlue}{\bullet} \, v_{OUT} - V_{BE, \, ON} + V_{OP} &= 0
\\
 &= 
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's RGB not rgb. Read the documentation carefully I guess

Comment: Why doesn't it results in an error though (255 > 1). Seems like a common mistake

Comment: Hello @user202729 thank you very much.

Comment: @user202729 yes, can you report my question as a duplicate please?